# Mongoose lookup on other collection without ref

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections, customers and downloads (for download history). On MongoDB native driver, i can simply do an aggregate with $lookup on downloads (in downloads collection, i have a customerId field). But on Mongoose, populate doesn't work at all.

On MongoDB Native driver i can do:

```
[
 {
   '$lookup': {
     'from': 'downloads', 
     'localField': '_id', 
     'foreignField': 'customerId', 
     'as': 'downloads'
   }
 }, {
   '$sort': {
     'createdAt': -1
   }
 }
]
```

Mongoose populate have some options that i can do that too? I don't wanna put all downloads IDs inside an array and put on customer, as a field. It will have to refactor so much code to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easier than i thought. Because mongodb native driver aggregate works for me. I simply use mongoose prototype aggregate (i didn't know that exists, the docs say that i should use populate instead of aggregate with mongoose).

Anyway, the code is:

```
Customers.aggregate().lookup(
   {from: 'downloads', 
    localField: '_id', 
    foreignField: 'customerId', 
    as: 'downloads'
}).
 sort({createdAt: -1})
```